# Facebook Graph API Comments vs Comments on Shares

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a api call to get post comments as such:

```
/{postid}?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(true)
```

This works fine and get this response:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "order": "ranked",
      "total_count": 2,
      "can_comment": true
    }
  },
  "id": "x"
}
```

However, this does not show comments on shares, which I have 8 of in that regard, bringing the total reported to 10 when it comes to that metric being pulled into overall engagements. Leaving out the 8 is where I fall short comparing the engagements facebook is showing me on the front end.

Does anyone know how to get the comments on shares as well as the comments? I can't seem to find the right call to make to get that. Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: If shares are made by users that did not grant your app permission to read their posts, then they are not available to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that call but only give me a `"total_count":1` and my post has 2, one mine and other from another person, you know if the field `fields=comments.limit(0).summary(true)` gives only comments I make from my page, only comments and not the responses to my comments or It´s about the permission of each user gives.

I using fetch in appscript, this is my call:

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{postid}?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=" + accessToken;
```